# Why does this (IID) random variable NOT follow Central Limit Theorem?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

We have independent identically distributed random variables $X_i$, which can only take values on selected integers with the following probabilities:
$$p(1) = 70/128$$
$$p(9) = 42/128$$
$$p(25) = 14/128$$
$$p(49) = 2/128$$
probability for any other integers are $0$.

Numerical simulations show that the sample average:
$${\displaystyle {\bar {X}}_{n}\equiv {\frac {X_{1}+\cdots +X_{n}}{n}}}$$
does **NOT** follow central limit theorem (there is no sign of converge to a normal distribution), **why** ?

Comment: The central limit theorem says that $(\bar{X}_n - E(\bar{X}_n)) / \sqrt{Var(\bar{X}_n)} \to_d N(0, 1)$. Your quantity converges a.s. to $E(X_1)$ by the law of large numbers

Comment: Please show your method and results.

Comment: You need to normalize so that the random variable has norm $0$, then divide by $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLT guarantees that $\bar{X}$ converges to a normal distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but it makes no guarantees about how quick that convergence will be. Here's what $X_1$ looks like as a line plot:

[image]

Here's what $\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i$ looks like when $n = 2$:

[image]

It's shifted a tiny bit towards being more symmetrical, but I will admit that it doesn't look very bell-curve-like yet. If we go to $n = 8$, it looks something like this:

[image]

Now there is a *clear* bell-curve appearing. It's still spiky, because there are plenty of values that it can't take, but the behaviour matches what the CLT expects.

If we take it up to $n = 256$, then we have something that is indisputably bell-shaped, although at this scale you can actually see banding of two different bell curves hiding in there:

[image]

If we were then to scale this, by taking $\frac{\sum X_i - n E(X)}{\sqrt{n Var(X)}}$, and plot it as a histogram, then you'd get something very close to a standard normal distribution.

Since I've updated the images to fix an error in how I calculated the probabilities, here's the hacked-together R code I used so that others can confirm that I didn't make any other mistakes:

```
oprobs <- rep(0, 49)
oprobs[1] <- 70/128
oprobs[9] <- 42/128
oprobs[25] <- 14/128
oprobs[49] <- 2/128

probs <- oprobs
probs <- convolve(probs, rev(probs), type = "open") # Repeat this line to double n

plot(probs, type = "l")
```

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect; the central limit theorem isn't about the sample mean. The sample mean is the subject of the strong law of large numbers; it converges (in a suitable sense) to the constant function given by the expected value.

Comment: It might not directly be about the sample mean, but it does describe the asymptotic behaviour of its distribution.

Comment: @ConMan, I could NOT reproduce your result. For example, in the case of n = 2, I got the peak of probability happens when index = 10. In your above 2nd plot, the peak of probability in your plot happens when index = 50. Whose result is correct ?

Comment: You know what, I made a rookie error in calculating the probabilities, and you are right that the peak should be at x = 10 rather than 50. I fixed up my code, confirmed that the n = 2 case lines up with what I got doing the calculations by hand, and I'll update the post with better images. You still get similar behaviour for larger n though.

Comment: @ConMan Thank you for your update.

Comment: @ConMan, why do we see "banding of two different bell curves hiding in there" ? Should we only see one bell curve according to CLT ?

Comment: Again, CLT doesn't say anything specific about the distribution of any particular $\bar{X}$ for a given $n$, it only tells you about the limiting distribution. The banding comes because of your particular initial distribution - some values of $\bar{X} = x$ can be achieved only through very specific combinations of the individual variables, e.g. when $n = 2$ you can only get $\bar{X} = 18$ from having 9 and 25 in some order, whereas you can get 50 from either 25+25 or 1+49. That's going to be a feature until there's a lot more overlap between the values, which will happen at bigger $n$.

Comment: @ConMan Thank you.